# I get an 'can not read property' error when trying to reload an iframe in js

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Please can you help me to find my mistake.
i want to reload an php document which is an iFrame. i do this with javascript.

HTML code:

```
<iFrame name="einträge" src="gaestebuch-auslesen.php">
```

JS code:

```
window.setInterval("reloadIFrame();", 1000);

function reloadIFrame() {
 document.frames["einträge"].location.reload();
}
```

The Error i get is:
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'einträge' of undefined"

Here the Code of gaestebuch-auslesen.php:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>G$auml;stebuch</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
 if (file_exists("gaestebuch.txt") &&
     is_readable("gaestebuch.txt")) {
         $daten = file_get_contents("gaestebuch.txt");
         $daten = explode("\r\n", $daten);
         for ($i = 0; $i < count($daten); $i++) {
             $eintrag = unserialize(base64_decode($daten[$i]));
             if (is_array($eintrag)) {
                 printf("<p><a href=\"mailto:%s\">%s</a> schrieb am/um %s:</p>
                 <h3>%s</h3><p>%s</p><hr noshade=\"noshade\" />",
                 urlencode($eintrag["email"]),
                 htmlspecialchars($eintrag["autor"]),
                 htmlspecialchars($eintrag["datum"]),
                 htmlspecialchars($eintrag["überschrift"]),
                 (htmlspecialchars($eintrag["eintrag"]))
                 );
             }
         }
     }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to do that is this one:

```
window.frames["einträge"].location.reload();
```

Comment: how can i achieve to reload the frame every 10 seconds?

Answer (score 0):

Simpler way with meta http-equiv:

```
...
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10">
</head> 
...
```

Comment: the problem is if i write this in the php file from the frame it reloads the whole page

Comment: but write it inside the iframe, not in the container

Comment: can you paste the code of "gaestebuch-auslesen.php" file? for example in: jsfiddle.net and put here the link